# How to force editing of a DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I can expose a DataGridComboBoxColumn on a grid, but the user must click it twice to show its drop-down list (the first is to gain focus and enter in edit-mode).

How can I force programatically to show the drop-down list?

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact answer to your actual question, but since the issue seems to be the need to click twice, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/more-datagrid-samples-custom-sorting-drag-and-drop-of-rows-column-selection-and-single-click-editing) blog post might help. It includes a sample to enable *Single-click Editing* in a DataGrid.

Comment: It didn't work for row-based selection. Still have to make two clicks to get the list shown.
Anyway, thanks.